# How to disable/inactive some of the GtkMenu Items

Tags: gtk, glade

I am trying to disable/inactive some of menu items under GTK+.  I have created Menu In GTK+Glade under C, and on some external event I need to disable some of the menu options.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use [`gtk_widget_set_sensitive(menuitem, true/false)`](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gtk/2.15/GtkWidget.html#gtk-widget-set-sensitive) to disable or enable the menu item widget.

Alternatively, if you used GtkUiManager and GtkAction to build the menu, use [`gtk_action_set_sensitive()`](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gtk/unstable/GtkAction.html#gtk-action-set-sensitive) instead.

Comment: One more question.. how can i get to know that which menu item is selected... i have created menu in Glade... can i associate some Constant ID or Enum Constant to each menu items... so in call back i can bifurcate functionality depending on Constant.

Comment: You can either attach a different callback for each item's "activate" signal, or connect all the items to a single callback and check the first argument to see what item was selected. See http://library.gnome.org/devel/gtk/unstable/GtkMenuItem.html#GtkMenuItem-activate for details.

Answer (score 4):

Using:

```
gtk_widget_set_sensitive (menuitem,FALSE); // to gray-out
gtk_widget_set_sensitive (menuitem,TRUE); //to enable
```

Answer (score 2):

Use with Vala + Gtk:

```
Gtk.Button play = new Gtk.Button.with_mnemonic("Play");
play.set_sensitive(false); // to gray-out
```

Answer (score 2):

There is also a checkbox inside Glade to disable the menu item:

Select your menu item --> Common --> Widget Flags --> Uncheck "Sensitive"

[image]